# Is it possible to only allow vorpal commands after a user has provided correct details

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, vorpal.js

I have a command that a user will provide their authentication details to and then once that is confirmed and valid, they can use any of the other commands.

Ideally I would like to go like this

```
$ app auth
  # User provides auth details
$ app another_command
  # Can now acces commands
```

However if a user tries to access `another_command` before signing in it should show them a message saying to run the `auth` command.

Whats the best way of doing this in Vorpal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make an external method that would be called that does all of the heavy lifting, and throw it into the `command.validate` method on each Vorpal action.

Sometihng like this should get you started:

```
function authFunction() {
  return app.authenticated;
}

vorpal.command('foo')
  .validate(authFunction)
  .action(action);
```

Comment: Oops - looks like it hasn't been documented! I'll add it to the `command` wiki. But its pretty simple - just return `true` if valid.

Comment: Just formally released command validation today in `v1.8.0`: http://bit.ly/1Q60yRF